# Java Sript Conditions for AcrobatDC/LiveCycle Designer

Tags: acrobat, livecycle-designer

I creating Fillable PDF (Invoice) in Adobe LiveCycle Designer. I want Automatic fill field Value.

My point is I have 4 Different Items with different `Code` and diffrent `Prices`.
I have to ask about two field `Field1 called " ItemCode"`  and `Field2 called "UnitPrice"`. I want `UnitPrice` field automatically filled with `ItemCode Price/Value`.

Following are the item Codes and their Prices:

> 018/22.50$
>
> 019/39$
>
> 020/16$
>
> 234/55$

I want JavaScript For Adobe LiveCycle Designer and Adobe Acrobat DC.

Million of thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear because of language problems I think. Do you mean: The user has to fill out two fields (ItemCode and UnitPrice) and then the Field UnitPrice should be automatically filled with ItemCode/UnitPrice (and that 4 times)? Or do you just want to select a product in a Dropdown and Display ist Code and Price in that UnitPrice field?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I want put ItemCode by myself in Item Code field and i want price would be come automatically in UnitPrice field.  Above 018 mean Item Code and 22.50$ is the Price and so,,,,,

Comment: You second Answer is near my Problem, i don't want Dropdown list in ItemCode field i just want put Item code myself and Price of that ItemCode would be come in UnitPrice Field

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (just one of many different possibilities:

1. Create a list of items, each item object gets two properties - `id` and `price`: (you can also write 22.5 instead of "22.50$" but then you'll have to take care of the formatting inside the `UnitPrice` field.

   ```
   var itemList = [
       {id:18,price:"22.50$"},
       {id:19,price:"39$"},
       {id:20,price:"16$"},
       {id:234,price:"55$"}
   ];
   ```
2. In the `exit` event of the field that you type in the id write:

   ```
   var idEntered = parseInt(this.rawValue); 
   for (var i in itemList){
    if (itemList[i].id===idEntered){
     UnitPrice.rawValue = itemList[i].price;
     return;
    }
   }
   ```

Let me know if you need any help understanding my solution! :)